# Technical confusion over "row" class in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

need to know if in BOOTSTRAP is it mandatory to use a `<div class="row">` before a `<div class="col-md-6">` or any.

Recently I saw a code which has the following mark-up

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
</div>
```

The above seems to be working perfectly over all devices. Now it should have been as per bootstrap a "row" which contains columns..

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
 </div>
```

I checked out the Bootstrap CSS too.. a ".row" has nothing but a margin of -15px left and right and it clears float by default.

Does substituting a row with column make any other technical issue or difference

Thanks

Comment: "row" is important when splitting columns.

Answer (score 2):

Your first code sample is invalid:

> ### [Columns (`.col-*-*`) can only be children of `.rows` or `.form-group`s](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E014)
>
> Bootstrap's grid system requires that grid columns must be children of grid rows (or `.form-group`s, because they extend `.row` in the Less source).
>
> Wrong:
>
> ```
> <div class="row">
>   <div class="col-sm-12">
>     <div class="col-sm-12">...</div>
>     <!-- You can't nest columns directly like this. This is missing a level of .row -->
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

The lack of `row` can mess up the columns' padding.